# Flutter MediaQuery vs constant value

Tags: flutter, dart

Until today, everywhere in my application(paddings, sizedbox bla bla) I was using Mediaquery. I wasn't using any constant values. For example if I want to place a container

```
Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1 ...);
```

But when I install my applications to another emulators, I started getting error RenderFlex overflow and I figured out it isn't true way to make responsive applications. So my question is when should I use Mediaqueries and when not use? Is my approach wrong? When I look at other examples, they using constant values and it works well. I tried it too and it's working fine so far.

Comment: Can you include a sample full widget?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) Package for responsive UI. I found it more efficient vs MediaQuery and tested it on various devices.